# 2D char array manipulation in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I am currently running into an issue trying to manipulate a 2D char array from an external function.

```
char* board[] = {
"first\r\n",
"second\r\n",
"third\r\n"
};
```

Later in the program, I want to manipulate an arbitrary single character in the array with

```
board[x][y] = 'A';
```

However when I reprint the board, the original values still persist.
The desired outcome of

```
board[0][0] = 'A';
```

Should be:

```
Airst
Second
Third
```

However it still prints as the original "First", indicating that board's value never got changed. How do I fix this to update board's value?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: literal string modification is implemented behavior and generally compiler define it as undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @Stargateur points out the core problem.

> literal string modification is implemented behavior and generally compile define it as undefined behavior.

Use:

```
char board[][100] = {
   "first\r\n",
   "second\r\n",
   "third\r\n"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays contains pointers to string literals, which you cannot modify.
Modifying a string literal yields undefined behaviour and in most cases they are
also on read-only memory. You will need to have a 2-dim `char` array:

```
char board[][15] = {
    "first\r\n",
    "second\r\n",
    "third\r\n"
};
```

then you can safely do `board[x][y] = 'A';`

Note also that what you've declared is **not** a 2D `char` array. You've declared an
array of `char`-pointers. What I've delcared is a 2D `char` array.